# How to check if a Polygon intersects a Polygon. (Java)

Tags: java, polygon, intersection

I need to check if an instance of `Polygon` intersects another `Polygon`. (The `intersects()` method won't do this because it only accepts a `Rectangle2D` or a rectangular area as an arguement).

If it matters, the two `Polygons` that I want to check if they intersect, are both of rectangular shape, but are rotated in an angel which is not 90 degress, so I can't use the `intersects()` method, or at least I think I can't.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Try converting the polygons to class Area. Use method "public void intersect(Area rhs)" from the javadoc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html

The `intersects(...)` method can take another area. Intersect the two areas to see if there is a remaining area by calling `isEmpty()` on the remainder.